# Are desktop processors really better than laptop processors that are 4-5 generations newer?

Tags: cpu

I've been researching on laptops for a while now, and while I knew earlier that desktop processors are much more powerful than laptop processors, I was kind of shocked when I pitched the i3-2100 against the i3-6006U on CPU benchmark (see [here](http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i3-6006U-vs-Intel-Core-i3-2100/m214467vsm41)). The core i3-2100 is 31% better than the i3-6006U, according to CPU benchmark.

Is there a catch here? Am I missing something? Or does the benchmark say what it says? Is a desktop processor really faster (or better, at least) than a laptop processor 4 years up the intel generation ladder?

Edit: Better, for purposes of this question represents this: which processor can handle applications and programs faster? 'Better' does not include portability or power consumption. I understand that these are processors designed for two different purposes --- I just want to, on a purely performance basis if the older desktop processor is faster/better (in terms of computing power alone) than the laptop processor. In other words, if one can both build a PC and buy a laptop and if one does not care about power consumption / portability and the like, what would one choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your position of better.

The i3-6006U is an ultra-low power CPU, with a 15W TPD.
The old i3-2100 is a regular desktop CPU witha TPD of 65W.

- Is the old CPU faster? Yes
- Cheaper?  Probably.
- Would it work just as well in a laptop when you are connected 24/7 to the power grid and have proper cooling and you are not in a place where power is extremely limited or expensive? Heck yes.

But if you also factor in battery drain on a laptop, heat generation, cooling noise etc then 'better' might suddenly have a new meaning.

<sub>Comparison: [CPU specs on ark.intel.com](https://ark.intel.com/compare/53422,91157%20ark)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Define "better".

Laptop processors are focusing on a different aspect than desktop processors.
While a laptop CPU is optimized for the best efficiency (thermals, energy usage, etc.), a desktop CPU is designed to have more processing power.

So yes, it is totally possible that an older desktop CPU is more powerful than a newer mobile CPU.